# Modulating audio signal with Euterpea

Tags: haskell, reactive-programming, audio-processing, euterpea

I seem to have a problem with choosing library for my project.
I have to write an application in Haskell to modulate, filter etc. audio.
Let's say I want to read an audio file and apply low-pass filter to it.

Is it possible to write the low-pass filter with Euterpea? 
The project should be done using reactive programming but I know that Euterpea uses Arrows and FRP.

I would really appreciate some information :)

Comment: See page 362 in this PDF http://haskell.cs.yale.edu/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/HSoM.pdf

Comment: Omg, thanks a lot @Arnon. I've been already reading Hudak's book but haven't reached that peage yet :) thanks again